# How to read a few variables from a file at a time? (c++)

Tags: c++

For a project I am supposed to pull 3 float variables at a time from an input file, use them, and then pull 3 more and repeat until there are no more variables in the file. I tried using this block of code below to pull them (I have already opened the input file for reading) but it is not working. I created a header file with the overloaded function openFile which will open input and output files and check to see if they opened successfully.

Minimal Reproducible Example

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float a, b, c, root1, root2;
    ifstream input;
    
    if (openFile(input, argv[1]))
    {
        while (input >> a >> b >> c)
        { 
            ofstream output;

            openFile (output, argv[2])

            root1 = a+b+c //for example
            root2 = a-b-c //for example
            output << a << b << c << root1 << root2 << endl;
        } 
        input.close()
        output.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do something like `while (input >> a >> b >> c) { ...` Not sure how the `x` variable is supposed to be read since you talk about 3 floats and did not mention `x` or its purpose.

Comment: Please make a [mre] (and explain the mystery `x` that @drescherjm mentioned).

Comment: I had not realized it was assigning a value to x every time as much as just checking to make sure that x had a value to see that the file still had values to input. one sec while I make that Minimal Reproducible example

Comment: Side note: You always want to check the stream's state to make sure the read was successful before you do anything with the data read. 1. Read data. 2. Make sure you read the data. 3. Use the data. If you do this in any other order sooner or later you're going to have to deal with bad input that exposes the bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code you've posted won't even compile. You declare `output` inside the `while` loop and create/open it (again and again and again) each time that loop runs ... but you call `output.close()` **outside** that loop, where the variable is no longer in scope.

Comment: *"but it is not working"* -- This is totally uninformative. If it was working, you would not have posted a question about it. *How* is it not working? Does it not compile? Does it compile, but when you run it, entering any number causes it to hack your local government's network in an attempt to get free ice cream? Something else? The usual guideline is to describe the problem, then provide (simplified) input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Thus is not a [mre], as it does not include the header files (those `#include`s...). Nor is `openFile` part of the standard C++.

Comment: If you tried to compile this code, the compiler must have issued a lot of diagnostic messages. Did you read them? Do you understand them? Can you debug C++ code?